# Loading 10Gb .raw file in C

Tags: c

I tried to load a 10Gb .raw file using fopen() function in c. My compiler is gcc , but i cant load the file, always the fopen() function returns a NULL. Can anyone help me to  solve this problem. I tried a lot, but i didn't get a solution.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Look into `mmap` for huge files, of course for a file that large, it only works on 64-bit architectures.

Comment: if `fopen()` returns NULL, it has nothing to do with what you believe are the contents of the file. If this is on a *nix system, try adding `perror("fopen");` after the failure, to get an indication of the reason for failure in your stderr path.

Comment: Try to describe what you've tried. I think fopen and the the correspoinding f functions should be able to read/write (as long as nothing else is being read/written and is not using i think 7? files). Do have read write permission on the file? `chmod 0666` it

Comment: `fopen` might fail to open large files if the program is compiled with 32-bit file offsets. In that case `perror` would say "Value too large for defined data type". Add `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` to your compilation command to fix it. (Exact message and mode-setting macro may vary by OS; the ones I gave are for Linux)

Comment: By using -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64, I opend my file. But i can't access the size of the file. 
fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_END);
size=ftell(fp);
But size always have a -1 value. Can anyone help me with this??. Thank u for all the answers, they were really useful

Answer (score 0):

Large file support with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` puts you in a situation where `fseek` and `ftell` aren't very good, because you can now have file offsets that don't fit in a `long`.

You have to change your `long`s to `off_t`s, your `fseek`s to `fseeko`s, and your `ftell`s to `ftello`s. Those are less portable interfaces (POSIX, not STDC) but that is unavoidable.

Large file support, ILP32 ABI, or the ISO C seeking functions: you have to throw one away to have the other 2.